# is there a code i can add to sort a dropdown list in alphabetical order?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, sorting

I need to sort the location items in alphabetical order in this search form: http://v2trgmanagementcompanycom.temp312.kinsta.cloud/portfolio/

The locations should be listed alphabetically. Can someone help with updating the below code?

This is the current code:

```
<?php 
$array = OSF_Custom_Post_Type_Portfolio::getInstance()->get_all_meta_field_value();
?>

 <div class="search-project">
                <form action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('osf_portfolio'); ?>" method="get">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center project-group">
                  
                        <div class="project-inner">
                            <select name="osf_portfolio_type">
                                <option value=""><?php echo esc_html__('I'm Looking For', 'rehomes'); ?></option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($array['osf_portfolio_type'] as $item) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr($item == $_GET['osf_portfolio_type'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-inner">
                            <select name="osf_portfolio_location">
                                <option value=""><?php echo esc_html__('Location', 'rehomes'); ?></option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($array['osf_portfolio_location'] as $item) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr($item == $_GET['osf_portfolio_location'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
             
                        <div class="project-inner align-self-end">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white;background-color: black;">
                                Search
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asort` PHP function. check the below code.

```
<?php 
    $array = OSF_Custom_Post_Type_Portfolio::getInstance()->get_all_meta_field_value();
    asort($array['osf_portfolio_type']);
    asort($array['osf_portfolio_location']);
?>
<div class="search-project">
    <form action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('osf_portfolio'); ?>" method="get">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center project-group">
            <div class="project-inner">
                <select name="osf_portfolio_type">
                    <option value=""><?php echo esc_html__('I\'m Looking For', 'rehomes'); ?></option>
                    <?php foreach ($array['osf_portfolio_type'] as $item) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( $item == $_GET['osf_portfolio_type'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?> ><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="project-inner">
                <select name="osf_portfolio_location">
                    <option value=""><?php echo esc_html__('Location', 'rehomes'); ?></option>
                    <?php foreach ($array['osf_portfolio_location'] as $item) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr($item == $_GET['osf_portfolio_location'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?> ><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="project-inner align-self-end">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white;background-color: black;">
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what happens to my site when i update the code: (critical error) http://v2trgmanagementcompanycom.temp312.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ScreenShot.png

Comment: @JasperZ did my answer help?

Comment: i was hoping you could help me with one more thing. Can we update the code so that when you select 'luxury rental' only the luxury rental locations appear in the next dropdown instead of ALL of them? And the same for when selecting 'affordable housing'. Let me know if you can help. thank you.